# Truncating an array of char via function C++

Tags: c++, truncate

trying to format this function as it will truncate an array of char (anything that the user enters it will split that up to a number the user also enters)

```
void truncate(char array[], int maxLength)
{
    // Variable definition
    int x = 0;

    // While loop start.
    while (array[x] <= maxLength)
    {
        cout << array[x];
        x++;
    }
}
```

The array parameter in the function header is just a string that was entered by the user, its an array of char. And the maxLength parameter is an int variable entered by the user as well, it could be 3, 4 or 5. The maxLength is supposed to act as the null termination whatever the user enters the string will truncate after that number.

But this code doesn't work, it doesn't display an output for the function. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're not really "truncating" the array, per se; you're simply printing out the first `maxLength` elements. Also put a newline at the end of each `cout`

Comment: oh yeah, I totally forgot about that lol.

Comment: Please don't tag a question with [c] if the question is for [c++].

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is this:

```
while (array[x] <= maxLength)
```

This is comparing the character returned from the array at x to the value of maxLength, so you're comparing a char to an int. I would recommend the more standard **for** loop for this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < maxLength; x++) {
    cout << array[x];
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much for your help man. Using the for loop right now.

Answer (score -2):

```
int truncate(const char *str, int maxchunk, char ***chunks)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    int nchunks = len / maxchunk + !!(len % maxchunk);
    char **table = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (nchunks));
    if (table != NULL)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < nchunks; i++)
        {
            if ((table[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * maxchunk + 1)) == NULL)
            {
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    free(table[j]);
                }
                free(table);
                table = NULL;
                break;
            }
            strncpy(table[i], str + i * maxchunk, maxchunk);
            *(table[i] + maxchunk) = '\0';
        }
    }
    *chunks = table;
    return table == NULL ? -1 : nchunks;
}
```